# Type-Filter Step in Gremlin 3?

Tags: java, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I would like to know how to apply a type filter in a Gremlin 3.x `GraphTraversal`. For example, let's consider the [Graph of the Gods](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/thinkaurelius/titan/images/graph-of-the-gods-2.png) as an example graph.

Here, we can do the following:

`Set<Element> set = graph.V().has("name", "jupiter").toSet()`

... and get a `Set<Element>`. **What I would like to have is an `Iterable<Vertex>` instead** (or a subclass of `Iterable`). From the traversal declaration, the result can only consist of vertices, because of the `.V()` operator. Due to the Java type system, it is needlessly generalized to `Element`. Is there a way to type filter this? What I would like to do is something along these lines...

```
Set<Vertex> vertices = graph.V().has("name", "jupiter").cast(Vertex.class).toSet();
```

... but there is no `cast` operator. Ultimately, the reason why I want to do this is because I need to iterate over the resulting vertices in a foreach-loop, and having to down-cast the loop variable as the first statement in the loop is annoying.

I'm open for alternatives, I'm still new to Gremlin 3 and there may be many things I'm not aware of yet.

Comment: What version of Titan/TP3 are you using?

Comment: I'm using Titan 0.9.0-M1, and the gremlin 3.x version that comes bundled with it.

Comment: That's a really old version of TP3 (M6 to be precise).  Working against the `titan09` branch and TP3 M9, i'm not seeing that casting problem as an issue.  It's possible that something changed in the generics to fix that problem somewhere along the way.

Comment: Okay, that would be nice. However, I don't think that I can convince my team to develop against a branch. Do you know by chance when the next Titan snapshot release (following 0.9.0-M1) will be?

Comment: TP3 M9 is up for release vote right now.  Expecting that to release in the next week or so.  I don't think Titan will release an actual 0.9 GA...it will go right to 1.0 when TP3 goes GA.  I think you're looking at a several more weeks at least.  If you think a Titan 0.9 M2 against TP3 M9 would be helpful to you, you might want to make such a request on the aurelius graphs mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Against Tinkerpop3 M6/ titan0.9 M1, the following should work:

```
Set<Vertex> vertices = graph.V().<Vertex>has("name", "jupiter").toSet();
```

Most of the M6 type issues can be resolved in a similar manner (parameterizing the method that produces the element by the expected type).